# How to get dotTrace ConsoleProfiler to collect snapshots?

Tags: .net, dottrace

I am running dotTrace's ConsoleProfiler ([dotTrace doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/10.0/Performance_Profiling__Profiling_Using_the_Command_Line.html)) on an application and keep getting a message saying:

"Profiling is successfully finished in 60.906 seconds

No snapshots have been collected".

What am I missing?

Console output:

```
C:\JetBrainsCLT>ConsoleProfiler.exe dotTrace_Config.xml snapshot.dtp
Console Profiler 2016.1 build 105.0.20160414.155338 Copyright (C) 2011-2015 JetBrains s.r.o.

...

Profiling is successfully finished in 60.906 seconds
No snapshots have been collected
```

dotTrace_Config.xml:

```
<root>
  <HostParameters type="LocalHostParameters" />
  <Argument type="StandaloneArgument">
    <Arguments IsNull="False">
    </Arguments>
    <FileName>C:\Sourcecode\Project\bin\Debug\Test.exe</FileName>
    <WorkingDirectory>C:\Sourcecode\Project\bin\Debug</WorkingDirectory>
    <Scope>
      <ProcessFilters />
    </Scope>
  </Argument>
  <Info type="PerformanceInfo">
    <MeasureType>Sampling</MeasureType>
    <MeterKind>Rdtsc</MeterKind>
    <InjectInfo>
      <SymbolSearch>
        <SearchPaths />
      </SymbolSearch>
      <Scope>
        <PatternFilters />
        <DenyAttributeFilters />
      </Scope>
    </InjectInfo>
  </Info>
  <CoreOptions type="CoreOptions">
    <CoreTempPath IsNull="False">
    </CoreTempPath>
  </CoreOptions>
  <HostOptions type="HostOptions">
    <HostTempPath IsNull="False">
    </HostTempPath>
  </HostOptions>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you should start this command line :

```
ConsoleProfiler.exe xmlfile <path_to_config> --save-to=<path_to_snapshot>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the described behavior can be caused by unexpected termination of a profiled process (someone killed the process, unhandled exception, etc.).